# Return integrated function using R

Tags: r, function, integrate

Let's say i have a function defined as the following in R:

```
> f <- function(x) 0.5*sin(x)*(x>=0)*(x<=pi)
```

i can do this to integrate it between 0 and pi:

```
> Integrate <- function(f,a,b) integrate(Vectorize(f),a,b)$value
> F <- Integrate(f,0,pi)
```

But if i want to evaluate and return some values of F i get this error:

```
> F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100))
Error in F(c(-100, 0, 1, 2, pi, 100)) : 
      function "F" is not found
```

i can understand that this is due to the fact, that my integrate <- function(f,a,b) returns a constant value C which is the result of the integration of f between a and b, but how can i return F as a function to be able to evaluate it's values as a vector and plot it ?

like in this case F should give 0 for any value less than 0 and 1 for any value bigger than pi and be variable between them.

Thanks.

Edit: just to sum it up more clearly: how can i define a function f(x) in [a,b] that will give me f(x) if x is in [a,b], 0 if xb ?

Comment: What do you expect `F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100))` to do? Return the result of `integrate(f,-100,0)` and `integrate(f, 0, 1)` and `integrate(f,1,2)` and so on? For some vector a,b,c,d you want the integrals between each subsequent value? You're not clear.

Comment: i expect F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100)) to return the values of the function F, which is the integrated function of f, that means it should return F(-100),F(0),F(1) etc ...

Comment: The integrated function of f between which two limits? `Integral(f, ?, ?)` Do you want the lower limit fixed at zero?

Comment: I will rephrase my question, how can i define a function f(x) in [a,b] that will give me f(x) if x is in [a,b], 0 if x<a and 1 if x>b.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your function call in an `sapply` and have Integrate return a function.

```
Integrate <- function(f, a, b)  function(x) if (x < a) 0 else if (x > b) 1 else integrate(Vectorize(f), a, x)$value
F <- Integrate(f, 0, pi)
sapply(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100), F)
```

gives

```
[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2298488 0.7080734 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: I will rephrase my question, how can i define a function f(x) in [a,b] that will give me f(x) if x is in [a,b], 0 if x<a and 1 if x>b ?

Comment: Thank you so much!! is there a way to make the Integrate function automatically work with vectors ? to use directly F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100)) instead ?

Comment: You can put the `sapply` inside the function declaration. `Integrate <- function(f, a, b) function(y) sapply(y, function(x) if (x < a) 0 else if (x > b) 1 else integrate(Vectorize(f), a, x)$value)`

Comment: Thank you very much for yout help